# How to test React async container components?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, asynchronous

On this video: [Egghead lecture](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-extracting-container-components-filterlink), Dan Abramov explains and gives a definition of container components. I really liked the idea of container components, but i'm trying to test them, when the container component does not have an async work the test is fine i just simulate some event on the component with Enzyme and then i check the resulting snapshot, but consider the following case when the component has asyn work:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.sendForm = props.sendForm;
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.nameChange = this.nameChange.bind(this);
    }

    nameChange(e){
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.sendForm({name: this.state.name});
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}> 
            <input onChange={this.nameChange} />
        </form>
    );
}

class Registration extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.sendForm = this.sendForm.bind(this);
    }

    sendForm(data){
        fetch(`sendsomewhere.com/?name=${data}`, headers)
            .then((result) => this.setState({
                result: result
            }));
    }

    render(){
        <Form sendForm={this.sendForm} />
    }
}
```

How do i know when the component worked correctly?

And this question is also for the case where the component does not have an asyn work: How do i know that Registration actually used the fetch function correctly? Since it controls itself and there is nothing being injected on the component?

Comment: perhaps return the fetch, then you can log or check against what that function returns. `return fetch(...)` and return the `result` you can check for a status code or something.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try returning like

```
sendForm(data){
    return fetch(`sendsomewhere.com/?name=${data}`, headers)
           .then((result) => this.setState({
              return result
           }));
}
```

then because `result` should be what that returns, you can do something like `formResponse = sendForm(data)` then `formResponse.status` for a 200 or something. This is loosely coded, and untested...something in the syntax may be off, but it's just to give a general idea of how you might get something to test against.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but i was thinking about test sendForm by simulating the click event with Enzyme. Another question would be if react guarantee if i make:
    enzyme(form).find('#submit-btn').simulate('click', mockObject);

    registration.componentDidMount = () => {}; May i be sure that the next componentDidMount call will be done because of my simulate event?

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you want to mount another component when the button is clicked. if so, then - assuming that nothing goes wrong with the submit and sending of the original form, then yes. It should reliably mount. However if submitting/sending the form has an error there is a good chance (depending on how it is coded, and errors are handled) that it will not.

Comment: React batch the updates, so if there are five mounts waiting to be done, react will do all of them and then call componentDidMount? I was not so clear before, sorry.